# How empty is the container in the phrase "More than half empty"?

Tags: meaning

Does "more than half empty" imply that more than half of a container is empty? Or does it imply that the container has more contents than if it were half empty?

Example phrase: "That glass of water is more than half empty."

Comment: What would 'three-quarters empty' mean?

Comment: What would 'more than three-quarters empty' mean? The ambiguity is in whether or not the 'more than' is associated with the 'half' or if the 'more than' is associated with the 'half empty'. If it is "more than" + "half empty", the container would be >50% full. If it is "more than half" + "empty", the container would be <50% full.

Comment: I notice that students and others often choose a word, phrase, or clause completely devoid of all context, and then ask if it is ambiguous... Worse still, native writers and speakers will give a word, phrase, or clause completely devoid of all context.  **It is quite impossible to overstate the importance of context in English** (and, I suspect, most other languages, too). If context is added the meaning becomes obvious.

Comment: @Greybeard In this case, the glass of water being visible to the listener was the context that made it obvious. However, in a case in which it was just heard, is there a rule of English that favors one interpretation over the other?

Comment: Absent other context, however, I think the plain meaning of this is that "more than half empty" means "the empty portion is greater than half of the total volume".

Comment: @Hellion I agree. Otherwise it would be "more than half full".

Comment: @WS2 also, if you parse it as "containing more material than a half-empty vessel would hold", then there's no difference between "more than half-empty" and "more than half-full"...

Comment: There is no ambiguity at all. More than half (is) empty. More than half (the glass is) empty. Nobody ever says "more than three-quarters empty", they say "almost empty". If you meant "more than half empty" to mean there is more than half the volume of liquid, you would say "more than half full".

Comment: @Axoren *However, in a case in which it was just heard* - this means "without context" - "without context" = *completely devoid of all context* - see above. (And you should not be listening to other people's conversations :).) *is there a rule of English that favors one interpretation?* No - only the speaker knows what he/she means. (There are no 'rules' in English - there is guidance. Some guidance looks like a rule... it isn't.)

Comment: In ['Something Happened' by Joseph Heller](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=X-CILqF-RugC&pg=PA99&lpg=PA99&dq=%22more+than+half+empty%22+meaning&source=bl&ots=WPnbeLIHnW&sig=ACfU3U2rreuoY-N8c4tsNwwpdgU0JLOGow&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22more%20than%20half%20empty%22%20meaning&f=false) we read 'The bottle of wine is more than half empty (or less than half full....)' This takes for granted the usual default reading of 'more than half empty': more than half the measure of the potential contents is missing.

Comment: @Hellion Yes. Clearly it is a matter of context. It depends on whether one is talking about "more space" or "more content".

Comment: @Ws2 you would have to get extremely contrived to offer up a context where "more than half empty" reads naturally as "more full than a half-empty container"; all the examples I've seen here so far sound like errors to me.

Answer (score 3):

As I see this construction, the adverb "more" modifies "empty", mainly, the particular state of emptiness being "half empty", and as such it specifies a greater emptiness than that which corresponds to "half-empty".

Comment: **1** "I asked for it half empty. I wanted to add the same amount of orange juice to it. That glass of water is more than half empty, it’s nearly full!" ++  **2** "It was half full when we left the house. Now, that glass of water is more than half empty! Someone has been drinking it while we were away."

Comment: @Greybeard I see your point about  dependency on context. This practice still isn't satisfying to me as in the absolute "that glass of water is more than half empty" is readilly  understood as "that glass of water is more empty than a half empty/half full glass". Moreover, allowing for a given utterance, out of two possible  senses, an undecided sense to be resolved according to the context, senses which are on top of that  the contrary of one another, seems to me to make for much contrivance in the language.